# How to hide parent control while showing child content?

Tags: wpf, visibility, parent, children

How can I hide a parent `TabControl` until the child in one of its tabs is clicked on? Obviously, I need the child to be visible for the user to be able to click on it. The only thing that I have managed to come up with so far is a bit of a hack... I'm displaying an extra child item over the top of the `TabControl` and then hiding it and showing the `TabControl` upon clicking. Here is my hack:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="600" 
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Grid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="300" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="250" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Name="TabControl" Width="350" Height="300">
            <TabItem Header="Original">
                <Rectangle Fill="Red" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Modified">
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTabControlVisible}" 
                            Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Style>
        </TabControl>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="0,22,0,0"
            PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Rectangle_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
            <Rectangle.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" 
                    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Rectangle}}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTabControlVisible}" 
                            Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Rectangle.Style>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTabControlVisibleProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsTabControlVisible), typeof(bool), 
            typeof(MainWindow), null);

        public bool IsTabControlVisible
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTabControlVisibleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsTabControlVisibleProperty, value); }
        }

        private void Rectangle_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, 
            MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            IsTabControlVisible = true;
        }

        private void Grid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!TabControl.IsMouseOver) IsTabControlVisible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I've changed the content to plain `Rectangle`s for simplicity.

How can I improve this situation? I don't like the idea of duplicating the child content to make this work. Does anyone have any better solutions?

Comment: Please read my question again... I stated that **I don't like the idea of duplicating the child content to make this work. Does anyone have any better solutions?** I'm now experimenting with `Adorner`s, which is one possible way of achieving what I am after.

Comment: What if instead of hiding the `TabControl` you would change it's opacity? Then you would have to control the opacity of the child.

Comment: There you go @mm8, a junior member has answered your question for you. A child element can be shown while it's parent is not by using its opacity. Thanks for asking me the very same question that I was asking the SO community... very helpful. ;)

Comment: And thank you to you too, @XAMlMAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, as @XAMIMAX mentioned, hide the `TabControl` but not by its `Opacity` (because setting it to 0 would hide the child too). The following `XAML`is just a quick & dirty proof of concept by hiding all the Elements except the Child:

```
<TabControl Name="TabControl" Width="350" Height="300" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <!-- Content of the Tabcontrol -->
    <TabItem Header="Original">
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Modified" >
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" />
    </TabItem>

    <!-- Triggers for the TabControl -->
    <TabControl.Triggers>
        <!-- Set Borderbrush to Black when tab is clicked -->
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Colors.Black}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <!-- Reset BorderBrush when Mouse leaves the TabControl (choose wathever condition you like to hide the tabs) -->
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Colors.Transparent}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TabControl.Triggers>

    <!-- Set "Style" of Container -->
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <!-- Hide Header -->
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <!-- Show header when Border of parent is Black (you can choose a different Property if you like) -->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=(BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)}" Value="Black">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

The Tabcontrol has 2 Triggers: Setting the `BorderBrush` to Black when someone clicks on the `TabControl` and setting it to `Transparent` when the MousePointer leaves the `TabControl`. Theese two handle the visibility for the `TabControl` itself. Note: Add additional `Trigger`s if your `Background` is different from the `Color` behind the `TabControl`.

The `TabItem` has a `Trigger` bound to the `Color` of the `TabControl` `Border`. If the `Color` is black, show the `Header` of the `TabItem` otherwise, hide them.

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting idea @LittleBit. It might actually work for me... I'm just trying it now and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Yup, that works for me. Thanks. Keep up the good work and you'll do well on this website. :)